# jmeter compatible version with jmeter-amf plugin?

Tags: apache-flex, jmeter, amf

I was trying JMeter to load test Flex the application and observed its having issue with [AMF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_Message_Format).
Explored more and found that there is a [plugin that we can use for recording flex application using jmeter](http://blog.everythingflex.com/2011/09/15/announcing-jmeter-amf-load-test-plugin/), tried that and somehow I didn’t find type as AMF under HTTP Sampler Settings.

Can someone please let me know the successful jmeter version that is compatible with jmeter-amf plugin, your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The [Requirements page](https://github.com/steeltomato/jmeter-amf/wiki/Requirements) lists JMeter 2.6 as the minimum supported version.